# FitNesse getting the suite name in SuiteSetUp java Class

Tags: java, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I have 2 pages a Suite page Suite1 and a SuiteSetUp page. Inside the suiteSetUp page I am calling a java constructor with the suite name as parameter.

now When I run my fitnesse suite I am getting the string 'SuiteSetUp' in java. I should get Suite1.. is it doable in FitNesse using java?

!|library                                | 
|suite set up|${USERNAME}|${suiteName}|

suiteName is defined in a template which is included to this page

suiteName is defined as follows. 
!define suiteName {${RUNNING_PAGE_NAME}}

this is how I included the template to the page the !define command is written inside the template page 
!include -c .FrontPage._TEMPLATE

Comment: Could you please post the fitnesse code where you are "calling a java constructor with the suite name as parameter"

Comment: it is added to the question

Comment: So how do you define `suiteName` in template and how do you do the include? and is there any default/fallback value for `suiteName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you include the template page in the `SuiteSetUp` page, which means the `RUNNING_PAGE_NAME` will be *"SuiteSetUp"*, thats why you are getting that value. (ok it may sound like I did not say anything... but that's a simple fact).

You can switch to `RUNNING_PAGE_PATH` or `PAGE_PATH` and perform string manipulation to retrieve the last token in java if you want to do it in a similar way.

Comment: RUNNING_PAGE_PATH is giving me SuiteSetUp instead of the suite page name

Comment: @Jobin from what I understand, Suite Page Name will never show up in `${RUNNING_PAGE_PATH}`, because Suite Page itself is never the running one. you are in fact executing SetUp/SuiteSetUp pages or test pages inside a suite.

Comment: @Jobin So as I suggested, you should probably look at manipulating the value from PAGE_PATH instead.